# Como tratar uma exceção de faixa de índice?

Tags: c#, .net, exceção

Estou com um problema de exceção no meu programa e não estou sabendo como tratá-lo.

Segue a imagem do erro no DataGridView.

[image: Erro]

```
private void DGW_solictacao_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.DGW_solictacao.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        this.txt_solicitacao.Text              = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        this.txt_cliente.Text                  = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        this.txt_Contato.Text                  = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        this.txt_solicitante.Text              = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        this.txt_representante.Text            = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        this.txt_atuacao.Text                  = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        this.txt_separador.Text                = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        this.txt_idcliente.Text                = row.Cells[9].Value.ToString();

        string strSQL = @"select 
                    SA.OBS
                    from tbl_SolicitacaoAmostra as SA
                    where SA.Cod_Solicitacao = '" + txt_solicitacao.Text + "'";

        comando = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conm);
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
            DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
            dados.Fill(dtLista);

            if (dtLista.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow dr = dtLista.Rows[0];

                txt_observacao.Text = dr[0].ToString();
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não existem dados a serem encontrados");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tá acessando um índice que não existe em uma coleção. Sem ver o código que está causando erro não tem como ajudar mais.

Comment: Não deve tratá-la, deve corrigir o erro de programação no código. Leia comentário acima.

Comment: Coloquei o código na pergunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está em uma destas linhas, no máximo na última, mas pode ser até uma anterior:

```
this.txt_solicitacao.Text              = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
this.txt_cliente.Text                  = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
this.txt_Contato.Text                  = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
this.txt_solicitante.Text              = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
this.txt_representante.Text            = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
this.txt_atuacao.Text                  = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
this.txt_separador.Text                = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
this.txt_idcliente.Text                = row.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/ItemDataTable.cs).

Ao que parece o último não deveria ser 9 e sim 8, a não ser que esteja mesmo querendo pular uma coluna. Mas se for o caso precisa ter 10 colunas, se tiver só 9, dará erro.

O código tem problema de segurança.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.